# Converting Virtual addresses to Physical addresses with a TLB miss

Tags: operating-system, tlb, page-tables

Suppose that you have a 64-bit system and that your OS is scheduling two processes  on it. Assume that the core has access to a 4-entry TLB for 4KB page size, and  full associativity. Furthermore, assume that the core has a 64-byte direct-mapped cache with 16 byte cache lines. Now suppose that your processes, A and    B, have 
the following page tables:

[Process A Page Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDGe2.jpg)

Now suppose that your OS schedules process A and in it, memory references to the following virtual address are made.

0x2002

For the memory reference presented above, detail all TLB access(whether they are hits or misses) and all cache accesses(whether they are hits or misses). Assume hardware page table walks and a physically addressed cache.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: No, this is part of my exam review. I'm unclear about what happens during the hardware Page Table Walker steps